# Can priests be on capital punishment juries?

Tags: catholicism, civil-government, canon-law, priests

Can priests be on capital punishment juries, or is this interdicted as an irregularity by canon law?

Comment: A thing to note which may complicate answering this question is that juries are largely a common law (English/American) thing whereas Canon Law is based upon Roman law, so while there is a good question here, it's quite possible finding an answer may be challenging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [1917 Code of Canon Law](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7786) can. 984 lists the following as [irregularities](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34308) to receiving (or continuing the exercise of) Holy Orders:

> 6.°      A judge who passed a sentence of death;
>
> 7.°      Those who take up the task of [execution] and their immediate and voluntary assistants in the execution of a capital sentence.

The corresponding [1983 Code can. 1041](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann998-1165_en.html#Art._3.) does not mention these irregularities.

[*Integralism*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7822) ch. 7, n. 18:

> the shedding of blood by the one who offers sacrifice is unfitting and traditionally causes the person inflicting death to incur irregularity. “*His a quibus Domini sacramenta tractanda sunt, iudicium sanguinis agitare non licet*” (“those who are to handle the Lord’s sacraments may not carry out the judgement of blood”); 11th Council of Toledo, c. 6.

Comment: A jury does not pass a sentence, and, thus, neither does a juror. A judge might pass a sentence of death, but if a jury is involved in a trial, they only determine guilt. The jury may know that capital punishment is a possible or likely outcome of their guilty verdict, but they cannot be held responsible for the death sentence rendered by a judge. I see absolutely no reason why serving on a jury which comes to a guilty verdict resulting in the execution of the person on trial should be considered having "carr[ied] out the judgements of blood."

Comment: @jaredad7 Yeah, [Dom Augustine says](https://archive.org/details/1917CodeOfCanonLawCommentary/page/n1802/mode/2up) it's only the executioner, not even those who pass a capital punishment sentence, nor the priests who witness the execution.